# Grouped table shows unknown row

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have created a report with VB.Net. I have used the following to group detail :

http://bidn.com/Blogs/remove-duplicates-from-tablix-by-grouping

The result is a table with an unknown value on the first row. It seems only to show up if the rows are more than five.

An image to explain :

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Is there any records with empty 'Blokkeklaar Aliasnaam'?

Comment: show us some code

Comment: Thank you A Friend there was indeed empty records.